# I'm writing a Haskell function that tests if an array of elements is a palindrome

Tags: haskell

I'm writing this function without using the built in reverse function and therefor having some difficulties

My function must use
class constraints to ensure that it will work for lists of integers, floats, and characters. Once I use class constraints my code stops working

Here is my code

```
reverseList :: [Int] -> [Int]
reverseList [] = []
reverseList (x:xs) =  reverseList xs ++ [x]
```

Here is my code with class constraints

```
reverseList :: (Eq a) => a -> a
reverseList [] = []
reverseList (x:xs) =  reverseList xs ++ [x]
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that is not working? And please also include the error message you get.

Comment: What do you mean by “it stops working”? Actually this function doesn't need any class constraints at all, it can just be unconstrained-polymorphic.

Comment: It stops working because I think I'm putting them in wrong. I will show how

Comment: error I get : Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a0]’ @leftaroundabout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type signature

```
reverseList :: (Eq a) => a -> a
```

expresses that this function can accept any input, provided it can be equality-compared (and give a result of that same type). So, you would be able to use this function in ways like

```
> reverseList 256
> reverseList False
> reverseList pi
> reverseList 'y'
> reverseList (Left "fubar" :: Either String Float)
```

What could possibly be the result of those?

The signature should instead express that it can accept *a **list** of any type*. (BTW, lists are not arrays.)

```
reverseList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

Actually, the `Eq` constraint is completely unnecessary, because you never compare the elements in the list, only the list structure. So, the simpler

```
reverseList :: [a] -> [a]
```

does the trick as well.

---

Another remark: your implementation is very inefficient, because `++` needs to traverse the entire LHS list, but that keeps getting longer and longer as you recurse down – a classic [Shlemiel the Painter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). **Exercise:** figure out why [the standard implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#reverse) does not have this problem.